# Knockout.js unable to process binding: undefined is not a function?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to implement a custom binding for an accordion-like document layout on a webpage, but I'm encountering an issue I can't easily solve.

Immediately on page load, I am presented with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "accordion: function (){return currentAccordionSection }"
Message: undefined is not a function
```

I have tried declaring my observable as both a function and normally in the `data-bind` syntax without success. I have initialized my observable with a default value (`null`) and it has not fixed this issue. Below is my entire ViewModel:

```
var libraryViewModel = function () {
var self = this;

ko.bindingHandlers.accordion = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        console.log(ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var section = $(element.text());

        //ko.bindingHandlers.css.update(element, function () {
        //    if (value === section) {
        //        return 'library-section-active';
        //    }
        //});

        //ko.bindingHandlers.css.update($(element).children('i:last-child').get(0), function () {
        //    if (value === section) {
        //        return 'fa fa-chevron-up';
        //    } else {
        //        return 'fa fa-chevron-down';
        //   }
        //});
    }
}

self.currentAccordionSection = ko.observable(null);
self.updateAccordionSection = function (section) {
    self.currentAccordionSection(section);
}

}
```

Some of the code above is commented out as it is not relevant to the problem at hand and I have disabled it to implement a reduced test case to narrow down the problem. Here is my binding declaration:

```
<h2 class="library-header" data-bind="accordion: currentAccordionSection, click: updateAccordionSection.bind('Text')">
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: A few questions. Why is your `bindingHandler` *inside* the view model constructor function? Typically you declare your bindings more to the top / at the start. Also, quite a bit of your code has been commented out, why's that? Finally, you have `element.text()` in your binding handler's code, but I'm unsure how that'd ever work since `.text()` is only a method on jQuery objects, not on HtmlElements that are passed to binding handler functions... (PS. If I fix/stub all those issues, [your code will not repro the error](http://jsfiddle.net/etaj369c/).)

Comment: For the first question, I'm not sure. That's how I've always done it. If it's incorrect I will move it elsewhere. Where would be the best place? 2) Because it isn't relevant to the question, but I wanted to include it anyway so I don't get responses like "please post all your code". 3) I am using jQuery as a helper

Comment: It's ok to include some additional code, it's just that you haven't explained anywhere *why* it's commented out, or how that's relevant. At any rate, it would be helpful to have a Stack Snippet c.q. enough code to actually reproduce your scenario. As you can see from my fiddle I do *not* have the error you get with code posted.

Comment: @Jeroen That's a fair point. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
 var section = $(element.text());
```

as per [knockout's documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html)

> element — The DOM element involved in this binding

`text` is a jQuery function not a DOM function so I think you are looking for something like:

`$(element).text()` or `$($(element).text())` instead? I'd assume the former since it makes more sense. 
As for the nested  binding handler I'm not sure why that is in the viewmodel since it's exposed on the knockout global object you're not protecting yourself from anything just making your code more unreadable. They are designed to be resuable so you can use them with different viewModels

Comment: Eugh, my code editor mashed my brackets, and didn't even alert me to the syntax error! Thanks. Where should I be placing my binding handlers, in any case?

Comment: Different file, global scope, the idea is that they are reuseable so other view models can use them not just your `libraryViewModel`.